# Kendo export multiple charts to pdf

Tags: charts, kendo-ui

I am trying to export multiple kendo charts to pdf doc. I see there is a pdf demo on kendo website but if my charts are inside div with fixed height, then when i click on export pdf, only chart that is visible at that time is exported and not all. How can i export all charts to pdf even if they are not visible? By visible I meant, I need to scroll down to see other charts so export pdf will export only that chart from div and not remaining ones. Here's the link

http://dojo.telerik.com/ugIvU/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the 'overflow-y: scroll' style to the topmost div and add a 'display: inline-block' to it as well and you should be good to go.

```
<div style="display: inline-block; overflow-y: scroll; ">
    <div class="demo-section content-wrapper wide">
      <div style="height: 460px; ">
        <div id="users"></div>
        <div id="applications"></div>
        <div id="referrals"></div>
        <div id="users1"></div>
        <div id="applications1"></div>
        <div id="referrals1"></div>
        <div id="users2"></div>
        <div id="applications2"></div>
        <div id="referrals2"></div>
      </div>         
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked but seems like my dataset is huge so unable to use this feature. Is there any 3rd party library to export large dataset charts to pdf on client side?

Comment: I'm not familiar with any libraries that specifically handle larger datasets, although Kendo should be able to handle just about anything you throw at it.  How big are you talking?  Don't forget to mark this answer as the correct one.  :-)

Comment: Late to the party on this one, but if anyone else is having a similar issue due to large exports, Kendo recommend including the [`Pako` library](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/drawing/pdf-output#configuration-Compression)